# Django Values() Method is not returing proper values

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I am trying get only some of column names in my Model, I am trying to use below query but it is not working, Could you please help me. what is the right way to use it.

**view.py**

```
def get(self, request):
        '''
        API function to Get all Objects
        '''
        try:
            emp = EMP.objects.all()
            serializer = EmpSerializer(emp, many=True).data
 
            return Response({'status': 200, 'data': serializer, 'message': 'All data'})

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return Response({'status': 500, 'message': 'Something went wrong'})
```

**Models.py**

```
  class EMP(models.Model):
    A = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    B = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    C = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, default='')
    D = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    E = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    F = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    G = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    H = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class EmpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EMP
        fields = ('A',
                  'B',
                  'C',
                  'D',
                  'E',
                  'F',
                  'G')
```

But when I was trying with below quires I am able to get all columns

```
 emp = EMP.objects.all()
```

If I am trying only some of the columns I am getting error

```
emp = EMP.objects.values('A','B','C')
```

Help me anyone, Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The `.all()` does not mean all the columns, it means all the records (rows).

Comment: Okay, But I need only some of the columns in row, what is right query or Methods should use ?

Comment: I am getting below Error If I am using

` emp= EMP.objects.all().values('A') `

` Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field 'D' on serializer 'D'.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the dict  instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'D'. `

Comment: `.only('A', 'B', 'C')`

Comment: Furthermore set the `fields = ['A', 'B', 'C']` in the serializer. The serializer determines what data will be returned/updated.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But I am using same serializer  more times which is for other purpose there i need different fileds

Comment: then you make two (or more) serializers, one for the view(set)s where you need all the fields, and one for the view(set)s where you need a limited number of fields.

Comment: One can make zero, one or *multiple* model serializers per model.

Comment: Okay, But Why `.only('A', 'B', 'C')` is also not working for me. and can't use single serializers with multiple views? Just question and what is the best pratcies ?

Comment: because that deals with what you *fetch from the database*, not what you present by your views. I had the idea that you only were looking to reduce the bandwidth between the database and the view, but it was more the view to the client.

Comment: Okay, now only the option is `fields = ['A', 'B', 'C']`  means multiple serlizers ?

Comment: yes, one that can for  example work with all fields, another one only with `A`, `B` and `C`, another one `A` and `D` for example. You can define as many serializers as you want for the same model.

Comment: okay Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `values()` after `filter()` or `all()`

In this situation, you can write something like this:

```
emp = EMP.objects.all().values('A','B','C')
```